# Why my function gameloop() can't reset my game and player.rect.x and player.rect.y position to in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I was learning pygame by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juRZLrUkDtU) (A little snake game). When the player is game over, the player can choose to quit or reset the game. In the latter case I call the function `gameloop()` again, which is were I am having problems

#### Code

```
# create a player
player = Player()

# create all levels
level_list = []
level_list.append(levels01.Level_01(player))

# set the current level
current_level_no = 0
current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player.level = current_level

# player position
player.rect.x = 70
player.rect.y = 360
active_sprite_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def gameloop():

  # set boolean default is false
  gameExit = False
  gameOver = False

while not gameExit:
    # loop for game over
    if gameOver == True:
        msg_to_screen("You Lose", constants.RED, y_displace=-50, size = "large")
        msg_to_screen("Press Q to Quit and Press C to play again", constants.BLACK, 50, size = "medium")
        pygame.display.update()

    
    while gameOver == True:
        # loop for key quit game dan repeat the game
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # event game quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                gameOver = False

            # event key atau tombol pada saat ditekan
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # config key Q for quit game
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    gameExit = True
                    gameOver = False

                # config key C for retry
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    # gameloop() # calling this function is doesn't work
                    # how ?
                    pass

    # config player control
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.go_left()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.go_right()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.jump()

    # Update the player.
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # Update items in the level
    current_level.update()

    # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
    if player.rect.right >= 500:
        diff = player.rect.right - 500
        player.rect.right = 500
        current_level.shift_world(-diff)

    # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
    if player.rect.left <= 120:
        diff = 120 - player.rect.left
        player.rect.left = 120
        current_level.shift_world(diff)
    
    # if player fall is game over
    if player.rect.bottom >= constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT or player.rect.bottom < 0 :
        gameOver = True
```

In that code, I created `gameloop()` function, just like in the tutorial, and I call the function in the case the player fails and wants to retry, but when that happens, the function is not working. The player can't come back in the start position.

Answer (score 0):

The position is not reset because `gameloop` does nothing to reset the position.  In programming, changes don't happen by magic -- you have to write the code to make those changes.  `gameloop` clears two Boolean variables, and does *nothing* else.

To make this work, you have to identify which initialization you need to do only once (such as creating the board levels) and which you need to do for every new game.  You need to move the "every game" items inside `gameloop`, something like this:

```
def gameloop():

    # set the current level
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    # player position
    player.rect.x = 70
    player.rect.y = 360
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # set boolean default is false
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
```

I'm not sure I got them all right; that level of detail and review is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  I expect that this change will help you move along in programming the game.